# How to use a macro variable in the from table in proc SQL

Tags: sql, variables, macros

I need to use a macro variable in the SQL pass through code below but keep on getting an error and I don't know how to fix it!

```
%let mon1 = 201209;
proc sql;
/*Connection String*/
connect to odbc as sqldata (noprompt="uid=dr;pwd=raven;dsn=FinanceDW;") ;
create table output1 as /*This will create a SAS data set*/
 select * /*this will select all from the command below and insert into the SAS         dataset*/
  from connection to sqldata
     ( /*Insert SQL CODE below - it can only use SQL any SAS code will cause it to fail*/
select top 10 *     
from "AUS_&mon1._FCM15.dbo.contract"

   );/*End SQL code*/

disconnect from sqldata;/*Close connection*/
quit;
```

I then get the following error (extract from log):

```
23          select top 10 *     
24          from "AUS_&mon1._FCM15.dbo.contract"
25         
26                );
ERROR: CLI describe error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 
       'AUS_201209_FCM15.dbo.contract'. : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) 
       could not be prepared.
```

The actual table I need to get the data from is called AUS_201209_FCM15 so I dont know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Needed to use `%bquote` and remove `""`:

```
%let mon1 = 201209; 
proc sql; 
connect to odbc as sqldata (noprompt="uid=dr;pwd=raven;dsn=FinanceDW;") ; 
create table output1 as 
select * 
from connection to sqldata     
select top 10 *      
from %bquote(AUS_&mon1._FCM15.dbo.contract)
);
disconnect from sqldata
quit;
```